# What statistical method would I apply?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, ancova, methodology

Basic information for my project is below;

- RCT
- Group(3); A type Exercise, B type Exercise, No(Control)
- Time(3 times measurements); baseline, 4wk, 8wk
- Outcome; mental health (continuous variable)

-Hypotheses;
Exercises affect positively on mental health as below order
A>B>Control
(I'd like to know whether the positive effect of exercise produced after just 4 weeks)

Though randomized allocation was administered, the outcome of the 3 groups at baseline was significantly different.
Thus, what kind of statistic tool would I apply?

I am thinking (1) repeated measured ANCOVA or (2) ANCOVA (baseline-4 / baseline-8) or (3) LMM.

Which do I choose?